# Having trouble creating arrays of type classes in c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to make a simple program for a college assignment where books can be added and viewed within the program.

im getting errors with my array such as: unknown override specifier, syntax error: missing ',' before '[' , syntax error: missing ')' before ';', unexpected token(s) preceding ';'. Any help would be appreciated

```
//Header.h

class Eason {
    int b=0;
    book array[100];
protected:
    std::string title;
    std::string publisher;
    int numInStock;
public:
    void addBook(std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string);
    void search(std::string);

};

class book:public Eason {
    std::string author;
    int edition;
    std::string barcode;
public:
    book();
    ~book();
    void setValues(std::string, std::string,int,  std::string, std::string);
    void printValues();
};

//class.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Eason::addBook(string author, string title, int edition, string 
publisher, string barcode)
{ 
    array[b].setValues(author, title, edition, publisher, barcode);
}
void Eason::search(string title)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (array[i].title == title)
        {
            array[i].printValues();
            break;
        }
        if (array[i].title.length==0)
        {
            cout << "Book not found" << endl;
        }
    }
}

book::book()
{

}
book::~book()
{

}
void book::setValues(string author, string title, int edition, string 
publisher, string barcode)
{
    author = author;
    title = title;
    edition = edition;
    publisher = publisher;
    barcode = barcode;
}
void book::printValues()
{
    cout << "Title: " << title << "\nAuthor: " << author << endl;

}

//stdafx.h
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Header.h"

//main
```

Comment: That makes no sense, neither from a code nor a design perspective. What is the `Eason` class supposed to be? What makes it different from a `book`? And more importantly, what makes a `book` also be an `Eason`?

Comment: `book` inherits from `Eason` but `Eason` has a member of type `book`. Therefore `book` has a member of type `book`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, Eason is a shop selling both magazines and books, i am currently only working on the book part of the question i will later add in magazines as an extra class .

Comment: i am trying to store the information on each book in the book array in the eason class.

Comment: Unrelated to your question and current problem, but there are two other problems in your code. First of all, is `Eason::b` supposed to be the size of the `Eason::array` array? Then perhaps you should *increment* it when adding a book? And when searching, are you *sure* there will always be exactly 100 books added to the collection before calling the `search` function?

Comment: If `Eason` is the container of books, the it is totally unrelated from the books themselves. Remember that inheritance is an ***is-a*** relationship. Books are clearly not an Eason, so the inheritance is wrong. If you remove that inheritance the decoupling means you can define the `Eason` class *after* the `book` class quite easily.

Comment: Yes i forgot to add the incrementation after adding the book, ok that makes sense actually, thanks.

Comment: Ive gotten rid of the inheritance now, but still getting errors with the array.

Comment: You might want to consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` to store your books. Those classes will take care of the bookkeeping. And really, no pun intended.